# Flutter How to get active network information?

Tags: flutter

Even though I'm using carrier_info and flutter, it outputs information for two SIM cards. however, I am unable to identify the current SIM card that offers mobile data.

```
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        androidInfo = await CarrierInfo.getAndroidInfo();
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        iosInfo = await CarrierInfo.getIosInfo();
      }
      print(androidInfo);
      print(iosInfo );
```